# Can I force my ex-spouse to remove my name from a loan?

Tags: california, divorce, loan

In California, my girlfriend is on a mortgage with her ex-husband. In the divorce, she agreed that the property was his, but her name remained on the loan. Later, the ex-husband re-financed the house and she signed those loan documents also after being pressured by her ex (He refused to allow her legal visitation at the time of child-handoff until she signed them. I recall the incident as should her lawyer who told her to go ahead and sign the papers). I feel like she got bad legal advice at the time and wonder if the ex-husband's behavior doesn't amount to extortion. She wants to get her name off of the loan. Is that possible and if so, what field should the new potential lawyer specialize in?

Comment: Why would the bank let anyone off the hook?

Comment: You need a contract law lawyer, specifically one who can litigate duress. Contracts signed under duress may be void but the problem is proving it. She should have called the bank the next day and told them that she was forced to sign it under duress.